# Can't use out-gridview since installing PowerGUI with Powershell V3

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Just wondering if anyone seen this and knows a workaround.

I'm Running Windows 7 64bit and just upgraded to Powershell V3.  Since then, i can't use out-gridview commands.  I get the following error.

To use the Out-GridView cmdlet, install the Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment feature from Server Manager. (Could not load file or assembly '
Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalHost, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file sp
ecified.)

I have opened the native MS ISE and can run out-gridview withgout error.

Answer (score 1):

PowerGUI Script Editor launches using PowerShell v.2, even though you have PowerShell v.3 installed. Launching Script Editor with the "-version 3.0" option resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check:

1. When you installed PowerShell V3, did you also make sure to install the `PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE)`.
2. Make sure you have `Microsoft .NET Framework v3.5 with Service Pack 1` installed also.

[Source of answer](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/640499/out-gridview-cmdlet-dependency-on-powershell-ise-is-not-documented)

Comment: Even with the ISE installed, PowerGUI still complains.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing -Version 2.0   to   -Version 3.0
Right click on Exchange Management shell and choose properties. Find above in TARGET.